# Poppulate a Quarter last date in Custom Closing Date

Tags: formula-field

Hi everyone I am new to salesforce, I have a requirement which says that when an opportunity is created I want to populate a custom close date field with the last date of that quarter according to create date.

for example - Create date - 2/10/2022  month/day/year
Custom formula field date - 3/31/2022 month/day/year

I hope you understand what I am trying to say, please anyone help me on this.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? You should [edit] your question to show us your attempt. If you're not sure where to start, then looking for modules on fomrula fields on https://trailhead.salesforce.com should be your first stop. The [Formula Operators and Functions documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&type=5&id=sf.customize_functions.htm) is also a good resource.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - I think you can create a custom formula field, and the formula would look something like this:

```
CASE(CEILING( MONTH ( {!$Record.Creation_Date__c} ) / 3 ), 1, DATE(YEAR({!$Record.Creation_Date__c}), 03,31), 2, DATE(YEAR({!$Record.Creation_Date__c}), 06,30), 3, DATE(YEAR({!$Record.Creation_Date__c}), 09,30), 4, DATE(YEAR({!$Record.Creation_Date__c}), 12,31), NULL)
```

You will need to replace the creation_date field with however it is named in your org. Please let me know if this works.

Comment: I am getting an error while doing this

Comment: Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'MONTH()'. Expected Date, received DateTime

Comment: I am using standard field CreateDate

Comment: CASE( CEILING(  MONTH(  CreatedDate  )/3 ) , 1,  DATE( YEAR( CreatedDate ),03,31) ,  2, DATE(YEAR(CreatedDate), 06,30), 3, DATE(YEAR(CreatedDate), 09,30), 4, DATE(YEAR(CreatedDate), 12,31), NULL)

Comment: Thanks, it worked, I didn't use DateValue Functionality to convert the Date/Time field to Date Field. Finally, it is done, thankyou brother.

Comment: @ZainKhan Awesome! I'm so glad it worked for you! Would you mind marking the answer as correct so it can help others?